# css sourcemap missing during compile, yet sourcemap is in same folder as css

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

I have an Angular 8 project in which I get the following warning at the end of compiling:

```
WARNING in Ignoring local source map at "C:\Users\mike\git\typhoon\bootstrap-reboot.min.css.map" as resource is missing.
```

Of course the first step is to check if I have the map file, but here's the weird thing, the css is included using these lines in `angular.json`:

```
"styles": [
    "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-reboot.min.css",
    "src/app/styles/styles.scss"
],
```

...and the `node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css` folder does indeed include the .map file right next to the .css file:

```
$ ls -l bootstrap-reboot*
-rw-r--r-- 1 mike 197610  4897 Oct 26  1985 bootstrap-reboot.css
-rw-r--r-- 1 mike 197610 76483 Oct 26  1985 bootstrap-reboot.css.map
-rw-r--r-- 1 mike 197610  4021 Oct 26  1985 bootstrap-reboot.min.css
-rw-r--r-- 1 mike 197610 32461 Oct 26  1985 bootstrap-reboot.min.css.map
```

The warning message indicates to me the compile process is looking in the wrong folder for the map file.

The final line of the .css file is:

```
/*# sourceMappingURL=bootstrap-reboot.min.css.map */
```

I actually don't care whether I get the map file or not since it's just a reset css, but I'd really like to get rid of this compiler warning.

Modifying the .css file seems like a hack which will need manually re-doing every time the package gets updated, so I'd like to avoid that solution.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just add `@import "~bootstrap/scss/reboot";` to the top of your `styles.scss` file.

Comment: Yes! Such a simple fix I can't believe I never tried that before. Thank you for the prompt answer. 'reboot' did not work, but `@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap-reboot';` did.

Comment: What version of bootstrap are you using?

Comment: currently version 4.3.1, but the problem has persisted for a while using earlier versions as well.

Comment: I have same issue, but I have tried several iterations of @import including Mike's and directly referencing the map import "~boostrap/dist/css/bootstrap-reboot.min.css.map" but still getting the compiler error. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Found that the scss import - @import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap-reboot'; works for me as long as I have removed the corresponding reference to the "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" in the angular.json. Only import in one place :)